# Interfacing HID device with Raspberry Pi

Tags: raspberry-pi, usb, rfid

I have plugged in a RFID scanner into the usb port of the raspberry pi. I noticed it appears in the `/dev/input/by-id` folder as `usb-RFIDeas_USB_Keyboard-event-kbd`.

I found code on [GitHub](https://github.com/google/makerspace-auth/blob/master/software/authbox/badgereader_hid_keystroking.py) that seems to suggest that I can read from this device, but I am pretty new to understanding all of this so I keep getting confused about how I can run the code to read information from my RFID scanner.